# Duda eliminar clases javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo esta duda, haciendo pruebas veo que estoy manejando mal el classList digo yo, pero igual no se porque no funciona este fragmento de codigo de la forma esperada por mi

```
const color=document.querySelector(".rojo");

 for(dato of color.classList){

    color.classList.remove(dato);
}
```

debiaria eliminarme todas las clases, pero me daja solo la de amarillo no se cual es el error :(

```
<h1 class="rojo amarillo verde" > color</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es que el método `remove()` además de borrar el elemento, también realiza una re-indexación. Entonces, el bucle **for** se estaría comportando de la siguiente manera:

- Accede al elemento con el índice 0, que es "rojo".
- Borra el elemento con el índice 0, rojo queda borrado.
- Reindexa los elementos, por lo que "amarillo" pasa a tener índice 0 y "verde" índice 1.
- Acabado el bucle, accede al índice 1, que es "verde" (aquí ya vemos que entonces se ha saltado el amarillo, dando como resultado que sea la única clase que se quede).

Aquí dejo un ejemplo para que se vea esto mismo que he explicado, modificando un poco el bucle para poder mostrar el índice del elemento que se está iterando:

```js
const color = document.querySelector(".rojo")

for(const [index, dato] of color.classList.entries()) {
  color.classList.remove(dato)
  console.log(`Se accede al índice ${index} para borrar el elemento "${dato}"`)
}
```

```html
<h1 class="rojo amarillo verde">Color</h1>
```

Una manera alternativa de eliminar todas las clases de un elemento del **DOM** sería a través del atributo `className`.

```js
const color = document.querySelector(".rojo")

color.className = ''
```

```html
<h1 class="rojo amarillo verde">Color</h1>
```

Comment: `remove` acepta varios parámetros, podría también hacer `color.classList.remove(...color.classList)` para borrar todos

Comment: Qué tal hacer el bucle al revés? Es decir, desde el último elemento hacia el primero. Así, si elimina un elemento, no se ve afectado por la re-indexación.

Comment: En ese caso deberías usar un `for (int i = último; i >= 0; i--)`